# How to stream local byte array in video player - Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have encrypted data file from which I am extracting my video content (mp4 file) in a byte array. And I want to play that byte array content in video player. I have checked plugins like cordova-plugin-exoplayer 1 but I am not able to do byte streaming in any player.

Can anybody please help me to do this.

Comment: Convert your byte array to base64 and place it in HTML% Video tag. but it will be a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks  @NajamUsSaqib... Is there any player availbale in ionic where I can stream  base64 data

Comment: I think No. You Have to use HTML 5 Video tag to play base64 video. otherwicve there are several Player you can use to play Videos via file path.